# Is it possible to create a ”timeline” using FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I know it’s possible to get a part of a file using the command:
ffmpeg -ss 00:02:00.000 -i input.mp4" -t 00:00:05.000 out.mp4

But is it possible to combine multiple videos with text and other effects?
I want to create a output from the following

File1.mp4:
Read from 00:02:00.000 to 00:02:05.000

File2.mp4
Read from 00:00:00.000 to 00:01:30.000
Insert overlay image “logo.png” for 20 seconds

File3.mp4
Insert the whole file
Insert text from 00:00:10.000 to 00:00:30.000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with FFmpeg, but it isn't really an 'editor' so the command will get long, unwieldy and prone to execution errors the more the number of input clips and effects you apply.

That said, one way to do this is using the concat filter.

```
ffmpeg -i file1.mp4 -i file2.mp4 -i file3.mp4 -loop 1 -t 20 -i logo.png \
-filter_complex "[0:v]trim=120:125,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];
        [1:v]trim=duration=90,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[vt2];
        [vt2][3:v]overlay=eof_action=pass[v2];
        [2:v]drawtext=enable='between(t,10,30)':fontfile=font.ttf:text='Hello World'[v3];
        [0:a]atrim=120:125,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a1];
        [1:a]trim=duration=90,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a2];
   [v1][a1][v2][a2][v3][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

I haven't specified any encoding parameters like codec or bitrate..etc. Assuming you're familiar with those. Also, haven't specified arguments for [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) or [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) like position..etc. Consult the documentation for a guide to those.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was a bit more complex than I feared – I have only been working with ffmpeg for a short time so I don’t understand half the input parameters